# Getting axis fault while runing axis2 webservice in jetty

Tags: web-services, jetty, apache-axis, embedded-jetty

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.clustering.context.DefaultContextManager.updateContexts(DefaultContextManager.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.clustering.context.Replicator.replicate(Replicator.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.replicateState(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:71)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:41)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:948)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please provide some context and not just post a stacktrace.

Comment: Yes contexts would be useful.  How about what version of axis2? what version of jetty? what OS? what JDK? what are you trying to accomplish (aka, what is your end goal)